# Create contiguous file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

Is it possible to create a large (physically) contiguous file on a disk using C#? Preferably using only managed code, but if it's not possible then an unmanaged solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly do you feel that you need a *physically* contiguous file? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm building a kind of nosql database and disk io performance is a priority.  Database solutions such as mysql, sqlserver always use contiguous files to boost performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a defragger?

It sounds like you're after the defragmentation API anyway:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The link from the bottom, cos it seems you've missed the C# wrapper that someone has kindly produced.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx

Comment: Yeah, maybe. But don't do this in C#.

Comment: To be honest, although unmanaged, this only solution presented so far that could produce a contiguous file, upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

Any file you create will be logically contiguous.

If you want physically contiguous you are on OS and FS territory. Really (far) beyond the control of normal I/O API's.

But what will  probably come close is to claim the space up-front: create an Empty stream and set the Length or Position property to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

With modern file systems it is hard to ensure a contiguous file on the hard disk. Logically the file is always contiguous, but the physical blocks that keep the data vary from file system to file system.

The best bet for this would be to use an old file system (ext2, FAT32, etc.) and just ask for a large file using seek to the file size you want and then flushing this file. More up-to-date file systems will probably mark a large file size, but won't actually write anything to the hard disk, instead returning zeros on a future read without actually reading.

```
int fileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 512;
FileStream file = new FileStream("C:\\MyFile", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
file.Seek(fileSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
file.Close();
```

Comment: Considering that the reason the asker wants to do this in the first place is (s)he is trying to implement a database, using an older file system is not going to work. FAT32 is specifically limited to a maximum file size of 4 GB. I believe ext2 has similar limits (somewhere around 2 GB or 4 GB), but I haven't any experience with that file system so I don't know for sure. There's also no guarantee that FAT32 is going to return a physically continuous block, either.

Comment: You are correct about that. FAT32 is more likely to do so than Ext4, NTFS of any other current file system, and especially journaled file systems. Of course it is no guarantee, but without accessing some file system level tools (like the defragmentation API suggested by others) this is the best suggestion I could make..

Answer (score 1):

To build a database, you will need to use the scatter-gather I/O functions provided by the Windows API. This is a special type of file I/O that allows you to either "scatter" data from a file into memory or "gather" data from memory and write it to a contiguous region of a file. While the buffers into which the data is scattered or from which it is gathered need not be contiguous, the source or destination file region is always contiguous.

This functionality consists of two primary functions, both of which work asynchronously. The [**`ReadFileScatter`** function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365469.aspx) reads contiguous data from a file on disk and writes it into an array of non-contiguous memory buffers. The [**`WriteFileGather`** function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365749.aspx) reads non-contiguous data from memory buffers and writes it to a contiguous file on disk. Of course, you'll also need the [`OVERLAPPED` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684342.aspx) that is used by both of these functions.

This is exactly what SQL Server uses when it reads and writes to the database and/or its log files, and in fact this functionality was added to an early service pack for NT 4.0 specifically for SQL Server's use.

Of course, this is pretty advanced level stuff, and hardly for the faint of heart. Surprisingly, you can actually find the P/Invoke definitions on pinvoke.net, but I have an intensely skeptical mistrust of the site. Since you'll need to spend a lot of quality time with the documentation just to understand how these functions work, you might as well write the declarations yourself. And doing it from C# will create a whole host of additional problems for you, such that I don't even recommend it. If this kind of I/O performance is important to you, I think you're using the wrong tool for the job.

The poor man's solution is **contig.exe**, a single-file defragmenter available for free download [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428).

Answer (score 0):

In short no then

The OS will do this in the background, what i would do is make the file as big as you expect it to be, that way the OS will place it contigously. And if you need to grow the file, you again grow it by like 10% each time.
This is simular to how a SQL server keeps it database files.

Open opening the FileStream you open it with append.

Example:

```
FileStream fwriter = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.Append,     FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
```

Comment: And that will ensure that on the hard drive, the file will be written to contiguously? I think not.

Comment: Your update still isn't correct. The OS doesn't automatically write files to physically contiguous positions on the disk, nor does it do it in the background unless you explicitly tell it to defragment (and even then, there are no guarantees on where exactly things will go). Physical contiguity is an important caveat to the OP's request. You're missing a few details on SQL Server's implementation.

Comment: NTFS will automaticly try to place the file ( IE if posible ) where it can be placed in one spot, this off course assumes you make the in 1 large chuck. Every time you grow it there is a chance it gets fragmented yes.   ( FAT 32 will not do the above thing)